# Do sea sponge cells transfer nutrients to each other?

Tags: cell-biology

Does a sea sponge cell transfer nutrients or energy to their neighboring cells or is their only symbiotic relationship that they are connected to each other forming a structure?

The sea sponges that I'm talking about are the ones that can be broken apart and naturally reassemble themselves.

[YouTube of the sea sponge I'm talking about.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N462jZFr13k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes choanocytes handle the bulk of sponges digestion and transfer nutrients to other cells. in some species Amebocytes also perform a similar function.